# Raspberry Pi 4 no wifi after update && upgrade

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, boot, pi-4

I am new to Raspberry Pi and Linux. I followed all the setup guides and have a 4" touchscreen with a case. I downloaded *MPI4008-4.0inch-2019-07-10-raspbian-buster.img* and flashed it to SD. I had to add *wpa_supplicant.conf* to the boot so it would connect to wifi on startup. Everything worked fine and wifi came up. Used rasp-config to set local and changed the password, rebooted everything fine wifi came up. Next steps update and upgrade. I used *sudo apt update* then *sudo apt upgrade*. No problems on the update but some errors on upgrade, so I did *sudo apt upgrade -f*. It finish no errors so rebooted now it comes up but no wifi try ethernet cable no connection. I have read many posts and tried almost everything I could find but no internet. When I try *rpi-update* I get:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: 
Connection timed out
 !!! Failed to download update for rpi-update!
 !!! Make sure you have ca-certificates installed and that the time is set correctly

**Update:**
I downloaded 2019-09-26-raspbian-buster.img and flashed it to SD. I ran update and upgrade with no errors. After reboot no wifi when the cursor is over the double red x icon it says: dhcpcd not running.

I tried to manually start dhcpcd by using *sudo dhcpcd interface* 
the output was:
*main: control_open: connection refused
interface: interface not found or invalid
dhcpcd exited*

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 2601:340:c580:a350::2f6a  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2601:340:c580:a350:e3a6:f851:b5c:c7d5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::69d2:1aa8:83f1:5e1f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:37:e4:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 76  bytes 29184 (28.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 29  bytes 3793 (3.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether dc:a6:32:37:e4:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 16  bytes 5284 (5.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 19  bytes 2860 (2.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
  ssid="snip"
  psk="snip"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I am not using rpi-update anymore. Not sure how to enable the wifi. The gui has a double red x icon and I get "dhcpcd not running" when you hover on it and nothing to select when you try clicking it. When using raspi-config I get the message "could not communicate with wpa_supplicant." So how else can I enable wifi?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down
```

I tried *sudo ifup wlan0* did not work got an "unknown interface wlan0." So tried *sudo ip link wlan0 up* it did not connect to wifi but, was able to scan wlan0.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: BC:64:4B:AF:49:07
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=-26 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"snip"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                Extra: Last beacon: 40ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000846616E647769636B
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                IE: Unknown: 460571D000000C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFFFF00000000000000000001000000000406E6470D00
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 7F080000070200000040
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD9F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001099A5D5D6BFEF5491AFB2B571720D3D201021001C41746865726F7320436F6D6D756E69636174696F6E732C20496E632E102300044150787810240008415078782D7878781042001253657269616C204E756D62657220486572651054000800060050F20400011011000941746865726F734150100800020004103C0001021049000600372A000120
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 02 - Address: BC:64:4B:AF:49:08
                Channel:36
                Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"snip"
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                          36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                Extra: Last beacon: 40ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000846616E647769636B
                IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                IE: Unknown: 030124
                IE: Unknown: 074C55532024011E28011E2C011E30011E3401183801183C01184001186401186801186C01187001187401187801187C01188001188401188801188C011895011E99011E9D011EA1011EA5011E00
                IE: Unknown: 200103
                IE: Unknown: 460571D000000C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF091BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1624050400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 7F080000070200000040
                IE: Unknown: BF0CB2018033EAFF0000EAFF0000
                IE: Unknown: C005012A00FCFF
                IE: Unknown: C30402C4C4C4
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD9F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001099A5D5D6BFEF5491AFB2B571720D3D201021001C41746865726F7320436F6D6D756E69636174696F6E732C20496E632E102300044150787810240008415078782D7878781042001253657269616C204E756D62657220486572651054000800060050F20400011011000941746865726F734150100800020004103C0001021049000600372A000120
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 03 - Address: BE:64:4B:AF:49:07
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:""
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                Extra: Last beacon: 40ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0000
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFFFF00000000000000000001000000000406E6470D00
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 7F080000000200000040
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 04 - Address: FE:64:4B:AF:49:07
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=-25 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:""
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                Extra: Last beacon: 40ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0000
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFFFF00000000000000000001000000000406E6470D00
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 7F080000000200000040
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
```

Now when I do ifconfig wlan0:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig wlan0 
wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether dc:a6:32:37:e4:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 8  bytes 3133 (3.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 21  bytes 2908 (2.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have tried many times and many things still no wifi after doing updates.  I reflashed the sd many times and still get the same problem.

This is what I get after update: Double red x icon, dhcpcd not running.
There are no networks to chose from.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="Snip"
    psk="snip"
}


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:37:e4:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 458  bytes 72723 (71.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22  bytes 3267 (3.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning: Network is down

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:37:e4:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:37:e4:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8  bytes 1097 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23  bytes 3461 (3.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigura
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0  error: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to get wifi?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status dhcpcd.service
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sat 2020-01-18 03:07:53 EST; 1min 40s a
  Process: 396 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SU
 Main PID: 429 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Jan 18 03:07:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: REPLY6 received from fe80::be64:4bff:feaf:490a
Jan 18 03:07:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: adding address 2601:340:c580:a350::31e5/128
Jan 18 03:07:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: renew in 302400, rebind in 483840, expire in 604800 seconds
Jan 18 03:07:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: leased 169.254.1.165 for infinity
Jan 18 03:07:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: adding route to 169.254.1.0/24
Jan 18 03:07:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: adding default route via 169.254.1.64
Jan 18 03:07:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: deleting route to 169.254.1.0/24
Jan 18 03:07:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[429]: wlan0: deleting default route via 169.254.1.64
Jan 18 03:07:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jan 18 03:07:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

******* **FRESH DOWNLOAD** *******

1. Downloaded Raspbian from raspberrypi.org site.
2. Used etcher to burn img to SD card.
3. Added LCD-show file(LCD screen drivers from GitHub) to SD card.
4. Inserted SD card into pi4 and followed startup screens. When it asked to reboot I skipped it so I could install LCD screen drivers. Used `raspi-config` to setup wifi and rebooted.
5. Everything was working fine internet came up and was able to surf the web.
6. Opened terminal and typed `sudo apt update`, it worked fine. 166 files to upgrade.
7. Used `sudo apt full-grade` had to run it twice it errored the first time.
8. Rebooted the pi and now no internet connection.
9. Tried to connect with the GUI no luck just get a No wireless interfaces found.
10. Tried to use `raspi-config` **Network Options** get message Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="********"
    psk="************"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I also did the same steps above without using the LCD-Screen drivers and get the same end result no wifi. I have read the foundation guidelines but cannot find what to do next.  Everything on the web seems several years old.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface dosen't support scanning : Network is down
```

***** **journalctl -b** command used          !!!!message was in red *****

```
Jan 22 14:41:50 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
!!!!Jan 22 14:41:50 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
Jan 22 14:41:50 raspberrypi kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
!!!!Jan 22 14:41:51 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
!!!!Jan 22 14:41:51 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Feb 27 2018 03:15:32 version 7.45.154 (r684107 CY) FWID 01-4fbe0b04
Jan 22 14:41:51 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[166]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.


Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Succeeded.
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Raspberry Pi bluetooth helper.
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Starting SDP server
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started BluezALSA proxy.
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Startup finished in 2.663s (kernel) + 13.368s (userspace) = 16.031s.
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[360]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested b
!!!!Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[360]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested b
!!!!Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Sap driver initialization failed.
!!!!Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jan 22 14:41:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bthelper@hci0.service: Succeeded.
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.19 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.19 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
!!!!Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi bluetoothd[753]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[360]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 169.254.1.165
Jan 22 14:42:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: probing address 169.254.1.165/24
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: Router Advertisement from fe80::be64:4bff:feaf:490a
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi kernel: ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time_ms in
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: adding address 2601:340:c580:a350:db34:3209:afe4:db0c/64
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::bcd6:d0ae:a078:5763.
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2601:340:c580:a350:db34:3209:afe4:db0c.
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Registering new address record for 2601:340:c580:a350:db34:3209:afe4:db0c on wlan0.*.
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: adding route to 2601:340:c580:a350::/64
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::bcd6:d0ae:a078:5763 on wlan0.
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: confirming prior DHCPv6 lease
Jan 22 14:42:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: adding default route via fe80::be64:4bff:feaf:490a
Jan 22 14:42:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: REPLY6 received from fe80::be64:4bff:feaf:490a
Jan 22 14:42:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: adding address 2601:340:c580:a350::dd95/128
Jan 22 14:42:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: renew in 302400, rebind in 483840, expire in 604800 seconds
Jan 22 14:42:02 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Registering new address record for 2601:340:c580:a350::dd95 on wlan0.*.
Jan 22 14:42:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: leased 169.254.1.165 for infinity
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 169.254.1.165.
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Registering new address record for 169.254.1.165 on wlan0.IPv4.
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: adding route to 169.254.1.0/24
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: adding default route via 169.254.1.64
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.1.165 on wlan0.
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 169.254.1.165.
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: deleting route to 169.254.1.0/24
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[431]: wlan0: deleting default route via 169.254.1.64
Jan 22 14:42:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Jan 22 14:42:06 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 22 14:42:06 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2601:340:c580:a350:db34:3209:afe4:db0c.
Jan 22 14:42:06 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Withdrawing address record for 2601:340:c580:a350::dd95 on wlan0.
Jan 22 14:42:06 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[350]: Withdrawing address record for 2601:340:c580:a350:db34:3209:afe4:db0c on wlan0.
Jan 22 14:42:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jan 22 14:42:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: "but some errors on upgrade" - would be useful to know what these were - what is `-f` option? if that's the same as full-upgrade, then perhaps you should start from scratch because some packages may have been removed

Comment: You appear to have used some customised image. This is a poor practice, and should not be necessary just to include custom drivers. Presumably the upgrade overwrote some customised files. We have no way of knowing what these may be. You will need to contact the author of the customised image, and request setup instructions.

Comment: Don't use `rpi-update`. It is only for testing unstable software. How do you enable wifi after flashing 2019-09-26-raspbian-buster.img?

Comment: What do you find with `systemctl status dhcpcd.service`?

Comment: Your question is very confusing (at least to me). You were originally using a custom OS - it is unclear what you are now using. You have run `rpi-update` despite the warning. You have not specified how you setup networking. Something you have done has impacted `wlan0`. You are running old commands e.g. `wpa_cli`. I suggest you start with a clean installation of [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) from the Foundation website. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: `ls /sys/class/net/` will list network interfaces the Pi is aware of.

Answer (score 2):

To verify your problem I have done a plain installation from scratch using the smallest image. Here is what I've done:

1. Downloaded [Raspbian Buster Lite 2019-09-26](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) onto a PC with Debian operating system.
2. Compared checksum

   ```
   pi ~$ sha256sum 2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.zip
   a50237c2f718bd8d806b96df5b9d2174ce8b789eda1f03434ed2213bbca6c6ff  2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.zip
   ```
3. flashed SD Card, assuming it is attached to `/dev/sdb`

   ```
   pi ~$ unzip -p 2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.zip | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4M conv=fsync
   ```
4. mounted boot partition

   ```
   pi ~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/p1
   pi ~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/p1
   ```
5. created file for wpa_supplicant with this content. Use your settings for `country=`, `ssid=` and `psk=`

   ```
   rpi ~$ sudo cat /mnt/p1/wpa_supplicant.conf
   ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
   update_config=1
   country=DE

   network={
       ssid="TestNet"
       psk="verySecretPassword"
   }
   ```
6. unmounted `sudo umount /mnt/p1` the SD Card and booted it with the Raspberry Pi 4B.
7. Checked if WiFi is working. **WiFi works**
8. Upgraded Raspbian

   ```
   rpi ~$ sudo apt update
   rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
   rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
   ```
9. Checked if WiFi is working.

One time I have found that WiFi does not work after reboot. It took some time before the RasPi connects to my internet router. With `journnalctl -b` I found some red error messages:

```
Jan 25 23:31:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[514]: wlan0: failed to request information
```

After some more reboots WiFi is working afterwards but I allways find this error message. It seems **dhcpcd** has a problem with **wpa_supplicant** now and does not work stable. I tried with disabled ipv6 by appending `ipv6.disable=1` at the end of the line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`. Then I do not get the red error message.  I will check if **systemd-networkd** has the same problem and will report it here as soon as I have checked it.

---

**UPDATE** with using systemd-networkd:
**systemd-networkd** has no problem with the updated Raspbian image. Here in short what I've done to verify that WiFi is working with it. For further information you may have a look at [How to configure name resolution with systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107455/79866).

Switch to systemd-networkd, don't forget to enable ipv6 again (remove `ipv6.disable=1` from the line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`):

```
# deinstall classic networking
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# apt --autoremove purge ifupdown dhcpcd5 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
rpi ~# rm -r /etc/network /etc/dhcp

# enable systemd-networkd
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service

# setup systemd-resolved
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
rpi ~# apt --autoremove purge avahi-daemon
rpi ~# apt install libnss-resolve
rpi ~# ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Configure wpa_supplicant with your settings for `ssid=` and `psk=`:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="TestNet"
    psk="password"
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
DHCP=yes
MulticastDNS=yes
DNSSEC=no
EOF
```

Reboot.

My suggestions to solve your problem are:

1. Check if you get the same results with my configuration
2. Try without **ipv6** by appending `ipv6.disable=1` to the line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`
3. Use systemd-networkd

Answer (score 0):

Just in case:
if you run your Raspbian on a external USB-Storage, you also have to update the (pre)booting partition.
The boot-partition decides which Kernel and drivers will be loaded. So if the kernel changes, both Raspbian Version diverge apart and the firmware can't found on the 'real' operation OS.